# Unable to click and "Accept Cookies" pop up in python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some information on prices from a website and get find the different prices for different states and cities. However, an "Accept Cookies" pop up shows up, and I need to click it for my code to be successful, but I am struggling to get Selenium to locate anything to click at all

here is the website www.kettlebellkings.com

here is the html for the button:

```
<button role="button" data-testid="uc-accept-all-button" class="sc-eDvSVe hSwgIR" style="margin: 0px 6px;">Accept All</button>
```

I've been using Expected conditions but it just times out every time. Here is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\msedgedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge('www.kettlebellkings.com')
driver.get(url)

element_present = EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(element_present)
try:
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]').click()
except:
    clicker = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", clicker)
```

But it just times out. If I leave out the expected conditions:

```
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\msedgedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Edge('www.kettlebellkings.com')
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]').click()
```

Returns:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[data-testid="uc-accept-all-button"]"}

It doesn't appear to be in an iframe either - what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Accept All' cookies button is inside the `Shadow Dom`, try the below code:

```
shadow_root = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#usercentrics-root").shadow_root
shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']").click()
```

You can refer how to handle shadow dom elements from the below links:

https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/shadow-dom-in-selenium/

https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver

Comment: This worked well, thank you - is there a way to pair this with expected conditions? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

you could try setting a cookie that would stop the pop up
just accept cookies on your normal browser, set them in the program and the website will recognize it as you/your account

```
driver.add_cookie({"name": "key", "value": "value"})
```

Comment: Curious about this - what would I need to set as the keys and values for each pair in the dictionary?

Comment: I think you need to use the cookie name (e.g. userid, or UserIndex on Office365), along with its value, you can access these values on your browser : https://www.cookieyes.com/blog/how-to-check-cookies-on-your-website-manually/ or https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add_cookie-driver-method-selenium-python/ (Sorry Im late, if orgot about this)